# GitHub API to retrieve files uploaded via issue comment

Tags: javascript, github, httprequest, github-api, octokit

Is it possible to retrieve a file that is uploaded via an issue comment?
Assume that I have

```
owner: foo
repo: bar
```

and there is a file on the path

```
https://github.com/foo/bar/files/1000001/text.txt
```

Then would this API call retrieve the data, **especially if the repo is private**?
I don't think so but not sure how to achieve it in another way.

```js
await octokit.request('GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{path}', {
  owner: 'foo',
  repo: 'bar',
  path: 'files/1000001/text.txt'
})
```

Comment: Did you mean the file path would be "https://github.com/foo/bar/tree/master/files/1000001/text.txt"? Also GitHub does not allow to upload files via an issue comment. Do you mean a file that was added using a pull request?

Comment: No, the file already exists at the path `https://github.com/foo/bar/files/1000001/text.txt
`. Then the request would fail. Now I understand that, but not sure how to retrieve it via the API (or even whether it's possible).

Comment: I'm not aware of such a URL. I cannot recall paths in the form of `https://github.com/[owner]/[repo]/files`. Can you share a working example URL to download such a file?

Comment: https://github.com/keita-makino/so-63841841/issues/1 Here's the example.

Answer (score 1):

There is no REST API endpoint to retrieve files that have been uploaded to a comment. The API call you mentioned ([GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{path}](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-repository-content)) is used to retrieve contents of the repository's source files only.

```js
const { data: { body } } = await octokit.request('GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/issues/comments/{comment_id}', {
  owner: 'foo',
  repo: 'bar',
  comment_id: '692203785'
})
// `body` is "[file.xlsx](https://github.com/keita-makino/so-63841841/files/5220043/file.xlsx)\r\n"
```

Extract the URL (`https://github.com/keita-makino/so-63841841/files/5220043/file.xlsx`) and download it with `octokit.request("https://github.com/keita-makino/so-63841841/files/5220043/file.xlsx")`.

I am not sure if that will work for private repositories though because the redirect URL to Amazon's S3 might require authentication that only works with browsers.

I'd also recommend to contact GitHub support: https://support.github.com/contact. Maybe the are planning on adding REST API endpoints for files uploaded with comments, and maybe there already is a way using the GraphQL endpoint

Comment: I sent a request. Let me see the reply and then give your answer a check.

Comment: Anyone figure this out?